# Function to Return True or False if First Letter of 2 words are True

Tags: python

LI am learning Python right now. I am writing a function that would allow in a 2-words string and test True if the first letters of both words are the same. I wrote the code below and I am so certain that it is supposed to work but apparently I am wrong. Any help please?

When I split the code separately and test it on a 2 word string as taking apart the (mystring.lower() [0][0]) and (mystring.lower() [1][0]), it works perfectly fine and leading me to the correct "True or False" results but in the consolidated format below, it is not returning the correct results.

```
def myfunc(mystring):
    for item in mystring.split():
        a = mystring.lower() [0][0]
        b = mystring.lower() [1][0]
        if a == b:
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

Results: (first letter of both words must be the same for function to be True)

```
my func(" Fred Newman") = False

my func("Bill Bowen") = True
```

Comment: You're using `item` as your loop variable and then never using it. That's already an indication that something is wrong with your algorithm. Go through each line and think about what each variable should be at that time.

Comment: Also `if blah: return True else return False` is the same as simply `return blah`.

Comment: # TigerhawkT3 .... Now that you mention it you make a very, very good point... I am not using item in that for loop whatsoever....Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to loop over the split string. Assign the split result to a variable, then test the first and second elements of the variable.

```
def myfunc(mystring):
    words = mystring.split()
    a = words[0][0].lower()
    b = words[1][0].lower()
    return a == b
```